# How can I make End xlUp skip over cells that have a formula in them but are blank?

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in column P that is referenced from another sheet by a formula, for example `=IF(OtherSheet!P107="","",OtherSheet!OP107)`.

This means that if cell P107 on "OtherSheet" is blank then the cell on active sheet will be blank too, but there is still a formula in that cell. `xlUp` stops on that cell because it sees the formula.

Is there a way to write the code so that it skips the cells that do not  have a value in them? Here is the snippet of code:

```
Set LastName = Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Offset(-0, -2)
```

I had no luck finding something on the internet, but probably because I didn't have the correct wording when searching.

Comment: Instead of using `.End(XlUp)`, use `.Find` with `What:="*"` and `LookIn:=xlValues` and `SearchDirection:=xlPrevious`.